# editing Static Resources in SalesForce

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

How can I edit Static Resources in SalesForce? 
While using css I need to edit and check it many times.

Comment: You cannot edit it in SFDC. You have to edit the file and re-import it in SFDC. But if you create a project in eclipse, you can edit it on the fly.

Comment: How we edit Static Resource in Eclipse?

Comment: Create a project in eclipse. And find the Static resource folder --> Your static resource. You can edit and save(Compile) the code.

Answer (score 1):

For UI work, many times you need to repeatedly edit CSS . The easiest way to do this till you finalize your CSS is not to move it into static resource.

Keep the CSS content in your VF page as inline text and edit it till you get it right. Once that is done, move it into a file and then save that file as static resource.